# Improving error reporting for a dynamically built module.exports in NODEJS

Tags: node.js, v8, stack-trace

I have an app that dynamically loads individual smaller files into module.export at runtime, it has been working well for a couple of years.

This is the main part of the code that iterates folders, reads them, and then appends them to the desired module.exports after a bit of validation.

```
  var path = module.path+"/lib"; 
  require('async').eachSeries(require('fs').readdirSync(path),function(file,next){
    require('fs').readFile(path+'/'+file,'utf8',function(err,code){
      var id = file.split('.')[0];
      if(id in module.exports) module.exports._errs.push({'lib':id,'err':'mod/'+module.name+'/lib/'+file.replace(/\.obj|\.fnc|\.str/,'.xxx')+' filename duplicated.'});
      try{module.exports[id] = eval('false ||'+code);}
      catch(err){
        module.exports[id]={'_err':err.message};
        module.exports._errs.push({'lib':id,'err':err.message})
      }
      next(); 
    })
  },function(){
```

This all works, but the issue is when there is an error generated, it appears that all of the files / objects / functions are loaded anonymously which make it impossible to determine from the stack trace errors exactly which function failed, as all appear to be anonymous.

Is it possible to either modify the code so that they are non-anonymous or alternatively modify the stack trace error reporting to show the code (& preferably variables) that actually caused the crash ??

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (/snapshot/src/x3-bin/source/mod/va/index.js:1:462)), <anonymous>:1:1642)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/snapshot/src/x3-bin/source/lib/mysql.js:1:2474)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/snapshot/src/x3-bin/source/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
    at Query.domain [as _callback] (/snapshot/src/x3-bin/source/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:468:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/snapshot/src/x-bin/source/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/snapshot/src/x3-bin/source/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/snapshot/src/x3-bin/source/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/snapshot/src/x-bin/source/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (/snapshot/src/x3-bin/source/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/snapshot/src/x-bin/source/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/snapshot/src/x3-bin/source/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/snapshot/src/x-bin/source/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
```

As you can see, the info to identify the source of the problem is very vague (eval at ) and impossible to identify exactly which module.exports function was the cause ?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (/snapshot/src/x3-bin/source/mod/va/index.js:1:462)), <anonymous>:1:1642)
```

Comment: This really begs the question, why do you need to use `eval` instead of `require`?

Comment: Also, setting properties on `module.exports` asynchronously is going to be really difficult to consume. The consumer will get back the module object when requiring the module this code is in before any of the properties are defined.

Comment: Thanks, but do you understand that I am including hundreds of individual files into a single module exports, I dont see how else I can do it other with eval() - which I realise is considered evil. This has been working in a live environment for over 5 years with hundreds of thousands of transactions per day.

Comment: Your `path` and `file` arguments are in scope in your `catch` handler.  You can add those to the Error object before you log it or just log it with the error.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to either modify the code so that they are non-anonymous

Well, `function(err,code){...}` is an anonymous function, `function NotAnonymous(err, code){...}` is not. See this example Node session:

```
> (function() { eval("let x; x.replace;"); })()
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (REPL9:1:15), <anonymous>:1:10)
    at REPL9:1:15
> (function NotAnonymous() { eval("let x; x.replace;"); })()
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at eval (eval at NotAnonymous (REPL10:1:28), <anonymous>:1:10)
    at NotAnonymous (REPL10:1:28)
> (function NotAnonymous() { eval("(function AlsoNicelyNamed() {let x; x.replace;})()"); })()
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at AlsoNicelyNamed (eval at NotAnonymous (REPL11:1:28), <anonymous>:1:39)
    at eval (eval at NotAnonymous (REPL11:1:28), <anonymous>:1:49)
    at NotAnonymous (REPL11:1:28)
```

Note how the second and third versions contain the snippet `eval at NotAnonymous`.

The other occurrence of `<anonymous>` (`<anonymous>:1:10` in my example, `<anonymous>:1:1642` in yours) is due to the fact that strings that get `eval`ed don't have a file name. To get change that, you'd have to stop using `eval`. The line/column information should be accurate though (at least, it is when I put an `\n` into a test string); so it looks like the file you loaded in this particular example was minified and had at least 1642 characters on its first line.

> impossible to identify exactly which module.exports function was the cause ?

You already have that information: in
`module.exports._errs.push({'lib':id,'err':err.message})`,
`id` is the export that caused the problem.

Aside from that, it really depends on what's in the files you're `eval`ing. If there are anonymous functions in there, then of course they'll show up as "anonymous", and you'd have to fix that in there by providing names for all functions.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping, appreciate your time. Apologies but "module.exports._errs.push()" just pushes the errors that were generated during the build process, it has nothing to do with runtime errors.

Comment: Also, my module exports should have the id of the function created with "module.exports[id] = eval('false ||'+code);" ?

Comment: @crankshaft Ah, I didn't realize you cared about errors thrown later. In that case I think the solution is to stop using `eval` and instead load the snippets with `require` or some other "official" import mechanism. Function names from within the modules should be available either way (as in my earlier `AlsoNicelyNamed` example), but of course they might be non-unique or just cumbersome to find manually.